# Why does 'std::vector<int> b{2};' create a 1-element vector, and not a 2-element one?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, uniform-initialization

I've been playing around with C++11 for the past few days, and I came up with something strange.

If I want to uniformly initialize an int:

```
int a{5};
```

But if I do the same thing to a std::vector:

```
std::vector<int> b{2};
```

Does not construct a two element array, but rather an array with one element of value two.  It seems like to get that effect one would need to be more explicit about it:

```
std::vector<int> c{{2}};
std::vector<int> d = {2};
```

But not like the declaration of b - this seems inconsistent.  I have seen some other stuff to the same effect.  What I'm asking - is this behavior in the final C++11 standard, or is it just in a draft that was implemented early?  If so, why did the standards committee include this behavior?  It seems like it defeats the whole purpose of uniform initialization, as one has to remember which classes have initializer list constructors, and to use the old () syntax instead of {} with just those classes.  Or one forgoes uniform initialization altogether.

This seems like a big "gotcha".  But there might be advantages to it that I am not aware of.

Edit:  this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a{2};
    for (auto x: a) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

outputs "2" on gcc 4.6.2

Comment: @ildjarn: I can confirm this on gcc, and since it has an initializer list ctor, it seems the correct thing to do.

Comment: Note that the (false) promise of uniform initialization does not mean you can everywhere replace () by {}, just that you can now use { } at a lot more places.

Comment: I'm not a C++11 expert, but I did just take a training class on it, and it looks right to me.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I know it's a false promise.  But it seems like it's harder to remember whether a specific type could have an initializer list constructor (which may change as well) for all the types out in the wild than to just remember the basic "class" of the type (primitive, struct, class, enum, etc), which shouldn't change frequently.

Comment: @RobertMason: which probably makes it a good idea to use {} only when you mean initializer list

Comment: @PlasmaHH : Or for value-initialization, since empty `{}` skips the initializer-list constructor lookup rule.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, sounds like a good rule to follow.  Though it does allow really clean return syntax.  But that's not worth the risk of forgetting that the type you're returning has an initializer-list constructor and then having to debug a strange error later.

Comment: @RobertMason: when its goes about return {a,b,c} then there is lots of ugly things waiting, like not benig able to do that for tulpes...

Comment: Maybe they can work the kinks out of this feature in the next standard so there aren't quite so many exceptions to look out for...

Comment: @RobertMason: A initializer list should be used to initialize a structure from a list.  It should _not_ be used to call arbitrary constructors.  I fail to see a problem here.  It would be _really_ inconsistent to allow the initializer_list to call arbitrary constructors as you seem to want.

Comment: @Mooring Duck: But that's exactly what it does.  And this was promoted as a feature.  All I would like is that if they are going to implement a feature like this that they be consistent.  If they're going to allow list-initialization to call arbitrary constructors, then (IMHO) they should require double braces to call the initializer list constructor to stay consistent with the other syntax.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, this behaviour is intended, according to §13.3.1.7 Initialization by list-initialization

> When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized
>   (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list
>   constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>   the initializer list as a single argument.
>
> — If no viable
>   initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is
>   performed again, where the candidate functions are all the
>   constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the
>   elements of the initializer list.

As to "the whole purpose of uniform intialization"... "Uniform initialization" is a marketing term, and not a very good description. The standard has all the usual forms of initialization *plus* list-initialization, but no "uniform initialization". List initialization is not meant to be the ultimate form of initialization, it's just another tool in the utility belt.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the clarification.  Why didn't the standards committee just require that people write std::vector<int> a({2});?  That way there's no need to have compiler implement a whole new initialization syntax and apply this to primitives.  If the purpose is to allow people to use {} in more places, then this seems like an antifeature.  Before () and {} each had their own place.  But now, {} can be use always, except when it can't.  So my gut reaction is to avoid the new feature entirely and use the old syntax to avoid annoying gotchas.

Comment: Alright.  Just saw your edit.  It's just unfortunate that everyone is selling list initialization as the be all and end all of initialization for c++ and touting it as a huge feature then.  I don't necessarily think that this is the most intuitive or consistent behavior, but there's a reason I don't get to write the standard :P

Comment: @RobertMason: It is a huge feature, but not by any means a "be all and end all".  I am unhappy that that is what people think this is, because it isn't true.

Comment: @RobertMason: The "annoying gotchas" that using the old syntax gives you are things like the "most vexing parse". That's far more painful to deal with than the few and relatively minor cases of wanting to call a non-initializer-list constructor on a class with a capable initializer list. After all, how often do you really use a `vector<int>`? This won't happen with a `vector` of non-integral (or float) types.

Comment: @NicolBolas Do you know *why* they decided to change the rules for overload resolution? Having `()` and `{}` select different constructors seems incredibly perverse to me. Why didn't they mandate something like `std::vector<int> a{{1,2}}` (double set of braces) instead of changing overload resolution? It seems so inconsistent and like they're asking for trouble (creating objects in a template utility function like `std::make_unique` comes to mind).

Answer (score 6):

Uniform initialization doesn't mean what you think it does.  It was added to make initialization more uniform amongst the types in C++.  The reasoning is this:

```
typedef struct dog_ {
   float height;
   int weight;
} dog;
int main() { 
    dog Spot = { 25.6, 45};
    dog Data[3] = { Spot, {6.5, 7} };
    std::array<dog, 2> data = { { Spot, {6.5, 7} } }; //only in C++ obviously
    return 0;
}
```

This is [valid C and C++ code](http://ideone.com/wuyb9), and *has been for many many years*.  It was *really* convenient, but you had to remember that this only worked with POD types.  People have complained for a long time that there is no way to do `std::vector<int> data = { 3, 7, 4, 1, 8};`, but some classes (`std::array`) were written in weird ways to allow initializer list constructors.

So for C++11, the committee made it so that we could make vector and other cool classes do this too.  This made construction of all types more uniform, so that we can use `{}` to initialize via constructors, and also from value lists.  The problem you are running into, is that the constructor overload with an `std::initializer_list<int>` is the best match, and will be selected first.  As such, `std::vector<int> b{2};` does not mean call the constructor that takes an `int`, instead it means create a `vector` from this list of `int` values.  In that light, it makes perfect sense that it would create a `vector` containing a single value of `2`.  To call a different constructor, you'll have to use the `()` syntax so C++ knows you don't want to initialize from a list.

Comment: "*It is not mean to use `{}` instead of `()` for constructors, that would be silly.*" In fact, that's exactly what it means if there are no constructor overloads that only take a `std::initializer_list<>` instance.

Comment: Stroustrup mentions in his FAQ http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#uniform-init that uniform initialization is meant for _all initialization_. But there are exceptions (like `std::initializer_list`s) where you have to use the "old-style".

Comment: @ildjarn: IMO it shouldn't.  If someone can justify to me why it _should_ call other constructors, [I'm willing to listen](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec).  In the meantime, I changed that sentence to something less controversial.

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion one way or another on whether it _should_ work, I only meant to point out that it _does_. ;-]

Comment: That doesnt explain uniform initialization though as they could have added initializer lists without adding the new initialization syntax

Comment: @RobertMason: What new syntax?  All that syntax was already there in C and C++ years ago, they just made it uniform by working on all types.

Comment: @Mooing : It was there in different contexts, but if something that didn't used to compile previously due to syntax errors now compiles under the new standard, I think it's safe to call the newly-legal syntax 'new'.

Comment: @Mooing, could you really initialize your dog structs without the = sign pre-C++11? dog d{0., 1}?

Comment: juanchopanza: No, that part _is_ new.  (I keep forgetting that's allowed).  @ildjarn: This syntax was previously only allowed for certain types, now it's allowed for all types.  I looked it up, and I think you're right that technically `={}` for classes counts as a new syntax.

Comment: @evnu: I just looked at his FAQ, and don't see anything that implies that `{}` should be used for all constructors.  He says that `{}` are allowed for all initialization, but that doesn't mean it can access all constructors nor should it always be used.  I interpret that as saying that `{}` is now valid in all initialization contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The standard states that the initializer list constructor takes precedence over the others. This is just one case where it isn't possible do just replace `()` with `{}`. There are others, for example `{}` initialization does not allow narrowing conversions.

Comment: Yes, this is supported by C++11 §13.3.1.7/1.

Comment: Yes, but to me it's the equivalent of taking std::vector<int> a(2) and then saying that std::vector<int> a2 does the same thing.  It doesn't seem very consistent to me.  And the whole point of uniform initialization is to allow more consistency AFAIK.  So why add this?

Comment: @Robert Mason, I guess one could read "uniform" here as meaning you can initialize an std::vector, std::array, c-style array, std::set, std::list and user defined collection types in the same way. I'm not saying it's great, it took me a while to get my head around it.