# why does `vector<int> v{{5,6}};` work? I thought only a single pair {} was allowed?

Tags: c++11, initializer-list

Given a class `A` with two constructors, taking `initializer_list<int>` and `initializer_list<initializer_list<int>>` respectively, then

```
A v{5,6};
```

calls the former, and

```
A v{{5,6}};
```

calls the latter, as expected.  (clang3.3, apparently gcc behaves differently, see the answers. What does the standard require?)

But if I remove the second constructor, then `A v{{5,6}};` still compiles and it uses the first constructor.  I didn't expect this.
I thought that `A v{5,6}` would be the *only* way to access the `initializer_list<int>` constructor.

(I discovered this while playing around with `std::vector` and [this question I asked on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/1td0dt/why_vectorint_v5_isnt_the_same_as_vectorint_v5/), but I created my own class A to be sure that it wasn't just a quirk of the interface for `std::vector`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this [answer might be relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9723448/1508519).

> Yes, this behaviour is intended, according to §13.3.1.7 Initialization
>   by list-initialization
>
> > When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
> >
> > — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of
> >     the initializer list as a single argument.
> >
> > — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
> >     the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the
> >     elements of the initializer list.

In `gcc` I tried your example. I get this error:

```
error: call of overloaded 'A(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
```

`gcc` stops complaining if I use three sets of brace. i.e.:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

struct A {
    A (std::initializer_list<int> il) { 
        std::cout << "First." << std::endl;
    }
    A (std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> il) { 
        std::cout << "Second." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a{0}; // first
    A a{{0}}; // compile error
    A a2{{{0}}}; // second
    A a3{{{{0}}}}; // second
}
```

---

In an attempt to mirror the vector's constructors, here are my results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

struct A {
    A (std::initializer_list<int> il) { 
        std::cout << "First." << std::endl;
    }
    explicit A (std::size_t n) {
        std::cout << "Second." << std::endl;
    }
    A (std::size_t n, const int& val) {
        std::cout << "Third." << std::endl;
    }
    A (const A& x) {
        std::cout << "Fourth." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a{0};
    A a2{{0}};
    A a3{1,2,3,4};
    A a4{{1,2,3,4}};
    A a5({1,2,3,4});
    A a6(0);
    A a7(0, 1);
    A a8{0, 1};
}

main.cpp:23:10: warning: braces around scalar initializer

    A a2{{0}};

         ^~~

1 warning generated.

First.
First.
First.
First.
First.
Second.
Third.
First.
```

Comment: I was using clang 3.3, I should make that clear that I hadn't tried gcc. And clang doesn't like three braces (unless the "second" form of constructor is present).

Comment: @Aaron clang does indeed complain more than gcc does. Although I think that's related to brace elision.

Comment: if gcc is simply providing extensions here, then I wouldn't be worried.  But it appears to give different behaviour than clang, *on the same code*.  (Although, I haven't done the experiments yet, and I'm too tired to think clearly!)  That's worrying.  (Bed time for me now though, I hope that I/we can get a good set of experiments tomorrow!)

Comment: Anyway, one last clarification:  Your quote from the standard mentions two "phases".  The first phase doesn't apply, as that would require `initializer_list<initializer_list<int>>` which is disabled (in one of my scenarios). Therefore the second phase is attempted.  But even in the second phase, "the candidate functions are *all* the constructors".  I've emphasized *all* here to emphasize that the `initializer_list` constructors are still candidates, even if they weren't picked up by phase 1.  (Personally, I think this a bad design, but no matter.) Is this the explanation of why `{{ }}` works?

Comment: @Aaron I think one set of braces is for list-initialization, and the second is for the initializer-list, but the braces can be elided.

Comment: I should rephrase. I think that `vector<int> v{ {5,6} };` is the same as `vector<int>( {5,6} );`.  This looks like an 'old-school' constructor call with one arg.  The value that is passed as the one arg is `{5,6}`, and that type of that is `initializer_list<int>`.  So the *inner* braces give us an initializer_list.  Agreed so far?  But the *outer* brackets (which replaced braces) have no 'special' or 'list-*' meaning.  I think this contradicts your last comment?

Comment: The code that that uses `A a{{{0}}}` is wrong - this code is incorrect if only a `A (std::initializer_list<int> il)` is present. Clang is completely correct to reject it (the reason is subtle and may not be obvious though).