# C++11 implicit instance in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I've this this kind of code used in some source, so I tried it and it works:

```
struct B {
    int x, y;

    B (int _x, int _y): x(_x), y(_y) {}
};

struct A {
    B b;

    A (B _b): b(_b) {}
};

int main()
{
    A a {{3, 4}};

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain how is this "implicit instance" constructed and point me to where it is documented? If I got it correctly, `A a {{3, 4}};` is a shortcut for `A a2 {B{3, 4}};`. Is this correct?

How can the compiler understand that I'm trying to get a new implicit instance of B if, for example, I overload the constructor so that it accepts another class that can be constructed with two ints?

Thanks

Comment: If you added another overload, that overload would take two arguments, so it can easily be distinguished from the present one, which takes one argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one constructor in `A` which matches an initializer list with two arguments. If you would add a second constructor to `A` which for example take a class `C` similar to `B`, than it would be ambiguous and give a compiler error.

The complete rules to resolve overloads are a bit complicated. Have a look for example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

Comment: Hmm.. *"which match with your two arguments"* I guess one could say that, even though it's simplifying a bit. `{3, 4}` is a single argument (initializer, but not an expression). It is checked against all three constructors, but two are forbidden via an obscure rule in [over.best.ics]/4 IIRC.

Comment: What are those "your two arguments"? I see only one argument?

Comment: I think my problem is that an exhaustive answer to this question is complicated, and probably beyond the scope of the OP; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20714273/420683 IMO your simplification describes the intent of the rules now.

Comment: @dyp: Are you sure the automatic constructors survive the declaration of the user defined one?

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, it's not a copy/move constructor that's user-declared. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to copy/move objects of that type (w/o explicitly defining/defaulting the copy/move ctors and assignment-ops). There'll be no compiler-generated *default ctor*, though.

Comment: @dyp: I agree that theses rules are complicated and I see no reason to repeat them here. The link in my answer should give a good first impression of how it works.