# Trailing comma in uniform initialization

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17, uniform-initialization

Is there any potential semantic difference when I use trailing comma during uniform initialization?

```
std::vector< std::size_t > v1{5, }; // allowed syntax
std::vector< std::size_t > v2{10};
```

Can I use trailing comma to make compiler to select `std::vector::vector(std::initializer_list< std::size_t >)` constructor instead of `std::vector::vector(std::size_t, const std::size_t &)` or are there any other tricks with mentioned syntax?

Can I use it to detect is there `std::initializer_list`-constructor overloading?

Considering the following code, which constructor must be selected?

```
struct A { A(int) { ; } A(double, int = 3) { ; } };
A a{1};
A b{2, };
```

This code [is accepted by `gcc 8`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WjPcjsCFGmDTrxFA) and `A(int)` is selected in both cases.

Comment: The 1st one (`std::initializer_list`-constructor) is always selected. https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yy6VtcK5ISCbzZJp

Comment: Anyway, there is no reason for `v2{...}` to call any constructor but the one taking `std::initializer_list`....only `v2(...)` will call `std::vector::vector(std::size_t...)`

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes, but what if there is only constructors with unary and binary arities with, possible, default function parameter initializers and other circumstances? Is there *any* semantic difference at all in all thinkable cases?

Comment: @jpo38 actually both v1 and v2 will call initializer_list overload, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723164/why-does-stdvectorint-b2-create-a-1-element-vector-and-not-a-2-element

Comment: @StoryTeller the OP changed the question while I was editing. I didn't just make a random change for fun. But still my bad. Thanks for picking it up and correcting.

Comment: @marcinj yes, so there is no risk to get the constructor taking a size as parameter to be called...so I don't understand what's the point in using an extra comma here...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, The C++ grammar rules makes the trailing `,` optional for *braced-init-list*. To quote [dcl.init/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#1)

> A declarator can specify an initial value for the identifier being
>   declared. The identifier designates a variable being initialized. The
>   process of initialization described in the remainder of [dcl.init]
>   applies also to initializations specified by other syntactic contexts,
>   such as the initialization of function parameters ([expr.call]) or the
>   initialization of return values ([stmt.return]).
>
> ```
> initializer:
>   brace-or-equal-initializer
>   ( expression-list )
> brace-or-equal-initializer:
>   = initializer-clause
>   braced-init-list
> initializer-clause:
>   assignment-expression
>   braced-init-list
> braced-init-list:
>   { initializer-list ,opt }
>   { designated-initializer-list ,opt }
>   { }
> ```

Secondly, you can't pretty much override the overload resolution system. It will always use the `std::initializer_list` constructor if you use such syntax and such `std::initializer_list` constructor is available.

[dcl.init.list/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#list-2):

> A constructor is an initializer-list constructor if its first
>   parameter is of type std​::​initializer_­list or reference to
>   possibly cv-qualified std​::​initializer_­list for some type E, and
>   either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have
>   default arguments.
>   ***[ Note: Initializer-list constructors are favored over other constructors in list-initialization ([over.match.list])....***

---

The program below prints `Using InitList`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct X{
    X(std::initializer_list<double>){ std::cout << "Using InitList\n"; }
    X(int){ std::cout << "Using Single Arg ctor\n"; }
};

int main(){
    X x{5};
}
```

Despite the fact that `5` is a literal of type `int`, it should have made sense to select the single argument constructor since its a perfect match; and the `std::initializer_list<double>` constructor wants a list of `double`. However, the rules favour `std::initializer_list<double>` because its an *initializer-list constructor*.

As a result, even the program below fails because of narrowing conversion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct Y{
    Y(std::initializer_list<char>){ std::cout << "Y Using InitList\n"; }
    Y(int, int=4){ std::cout << "Y Using Double Arg ctor\n"; }
};

int main(){
    Y y1{4777};
    Y y2{577,};
    Y y3{57,7777};
}
```

---

In response to your comment below, "*what if there is no overloading with std::initializer_list, or it is not the first constructor's parameter?*" - then overload resolution doesn't choose it. Demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct Y{
    Y(int, std::initializer_list<double>){ std::cout << "Y Using InitList\n"; }
    Y(int, int=4){ std::cout << "Y Using Double Arg ctor\n"; }
};

int main(){
    Y y1{4};
    Y y2{5,};
    Y y3{5,7};
}
```

Prints:

```
Y Using Double Arg ctor
Y Using Double Arg ctor
Y Using Double Arg ctor
```

If there is no *initializer-list constructor* available, then the `{initializer-list...,}` initializer pretty much falls back to *direct initialization* as per [dcl.init/16](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#16), whose semantics are covered by the proceeding paragraph of [dcl.init/16](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#16)

Comment: OK, what if there is no overloading with `std::initializer_list`, or it is not the first constructor's parameter?

Answer (score 2):

No. That comma is a concession to make preprocessor macro tricks work without compile errors. It means nothing about your data type or its size.