# Construct std::vector using initializer list with one element

Tags: c++, vector, initializer-list

Consider the following program, defining a std::vector containing the value 13:

```
std::vector<int> vec{13};
```

This could also have been interpreted as a call to the constructor that initializes the vector with 13 zeros. My question is: how does the compiler choose between constructing a std::vector with an initializer_list or by initializing the vector with 13 zeros?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723164/why-does-stdvectorint-b2-create-a-1-element-vector-and-not-a-2-element

Answer (score 3):

Because the construtor taking `std::initializer_list` is preferred in [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

> Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>
> - All constructors that take std::initializer_list as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have
>     default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution
>     against a single argument of type std::initializer_list
> - If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that
>     consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction
>     that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage
>     produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a
>     copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple
>     copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all).