# Is Clang or GCC correct in rejecting/accepting this CTAD code?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, ctad

Clang and GCC [disagree](https://godbolt.org/z/8zzsqn) on accepting this code.

What is the standard required behavior?

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector pairs = {std::pair{1,11},{2,22}, {3,33}};
    for (const auto& p: pairs) {
        std::cout << p.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note: I know this is C++ so it is possible that the standard is fuzzy, but I presume one behavior is correct.

Comment: Almost certainly not the cause of the problem here but, when using `std::pair`, you should really `#include <utility>` ... don't rely on the fact that other headers implicitly include that.

Comment: "@Nicol Bolas" (I wish I could tag editors) : I think c++20 was also valid tag since I care about current standard, it often happens something is introduced, and some corner case is clarified/fixed in next standard...

Comment: Interesting `std::vector pairs({std::pair{1,11},{2,22},{3,33}});` works for both.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The process of CTAD is largely defined by [[over.match.class.deduct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.class.deduct). Broadly speaking, the overload set is all of the accessible constructors of the type, plus any deduction guides. And the overload set is resolved per this rule:

> Initialization and overload resolution are performed as described in [dcl.init] and [over.match.ctor], [over.match.copy], or [over.match.list] (as appropriate for the type of initialization performed)

Since the "type of initialization performed" is definitely list-initialization, we move on to [[over.match.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.list). Where we get this infamous bulleted list:

> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors ([dcl.init.list]) of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

This tells us that `initializer-list constructors` are prioritized; they're given first crack at overload resolution, and in a very specific way (that is, building a `std::initializer_list` and passing it as an argument). However, Clang gives a telling error:

> ```
> note: candidate function template not viable: requires at most 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
>      vector(initializer_list<value_type> __l,
> ```

That is, it's trying to call that constructor as if "the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list." This suggests that Clang *skipped* the first bullet point when doing list-initialization through CTAD. The fact that adding parens around the braced-init-list "fixes" the issue also suggests that this is what is happening.

Oddly, it works for simple types, like an initializer-list of integers. And it works if you explicitly name each member as a `pair`. And Clang can `auto`-deduce the type of the `initializer_list` produced by `{std::pair{1,11}, {2,22}, {3,33}}` just fine. So this bug seems *really* specific.

Comment: Why is that bulleted list infamous? I'm not aware of the history behind that.

Comment: @cigien - ["Uniform" initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9723164/817643).